# Scoring parameter in GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, precision, gridsearchcv, scoring

I've run a Grid Search for a Random Forest Classifier with the scoring set to precision. The best score is 0.9639, great! But what does that tell me? Because, when I run the RF Classifier with the best parameters, I get a precision score of .85.

Thanks for helping!

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

    params_rf = { 'criterion': ['gini','entropy'],           
         'min_samples_leaf': [1,3,5,10,20,25,30,35,40,45,50]
                     }
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=2500,
                          random_state=SEED,
                          max_features='sqrt',
                          bootstrap=True,
                          oob_score=True,
                          n_jobs=-1,
                          class_weight={1:3},
                          warm_start=True,
                          refit=True,
                          return_train_score=True)

    prec = make_scorer(precision_score)
                        
    grid_rf = GridSearchCV(estimator = rf, 
    
   
    param_grid=params_rf,scoring=prec,cv=10,n_jobs=-1,
    verbose=True)

    grid_rf.fit(X_resampled,y_resampled)

    y_pred = grid_rf.predict(X_test)

    best_hyperparams = grid_rf.best_params_
    best_score = grid_rf.best_score_
    best_estimator = grid_rf.best_estimator_
    print('Best hyperparameters:\n', best_hyperparams)
    print('Best score:\n', best_score.round(4))
    print('Best estimator:\n', best_estimator)


    Fitting 10 folds for each of 22 candidates, totalling 220 
    fits
    Best hyperparameters:
     {'criterion': 'entropy', 'min_samples_leaf': 1}
    Best score:
     0.9639
    Best estimator:
     RandomForestClassifier(class_weight={1: 3}, 
    criterion='entropy',
                   n_estimators=2500, n_jobs=-1, oob_score=True,
                   random_state=121864, warm_start=True)



    # Run a Random Forest Classifier  (A)
    rf_A = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight={1: 3}, 
    criterion='entropy',
                   n_estimators=2500, n_jobs=-1, oob_score=True,
                   random_state=121864, 
    warm_start=True,min_samples_leaf=1                          
                          )
              
    rf_A.fit(X_resampled,y_resampled)
    y_pred_A=(rf_A.predict(X_test))
    importances_rf_A = pd.Series(rf_A.feature_importances_, index 
    = Features.columns)
    
    # Create a heatmap of the confusion matrix

    matrix =confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred_A).round(2)
    text = np.array([['True Positive', 'False Negative'],
            ['False Positive', 'True Negative']])

    # combining text with values
    formatted_text = (np.asarray(["{0}\n{1:.0f}".format(
    text, matrix) for text, matrix in zip(text.flatten(), 
    matrix.flatten())])).reshape(2,2)

    # drawing heatmap
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,2))
    sns.set(font_scale=1.3)
    ax = sns.heatmap(matrix, annot=formatted_text, fmt="", 
    linewidth=1,cbar=False)
    ax.set_title('Confusion Matrix', size = 18)
    plt.show()

    target_names = ['Fully Paid', 'Not Fully Paid']
    print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred_A,
    target_names=target_names,zero_division=1))

    # Create a horizontal bar chart of the feature importances

    # Sort importances_dt                                   
    sorted_importances_rf_A = importances_rf_A.sort_values()
    sorted_importances_descend_A = 
    importances_rf_A.sort_values(ascending=False)
    # Make a horizontal bar plot
    #fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 15))
    sorted_importances_rf_A.plot(kind='barh',grid=True)
    #ax.set_xticks(,minor=True)
    plt.show()
    print(sorted_importances_descend_A.cumsum())
```

Ruuning the RF classifier with the best hyper parameters:

precision    recall  f1-score   support

```
Fully Paid       0.87      0.65      0.75      1609
```

Not Fully Paid       0.22      0.51      0.31       307

```
  accuracy                           0.63      1916
 macro avg       0.55      0.58      0.53      1916
```

weighted avg       0.77      0.63      0.68      1916

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.score:%7E:text=%5Bsource%5D-,Return%20the%20mean%20accuracy%20on%20the%20given%20test%20data%20and%20labels.,-In%20multi%2Dlabel) it returns the mean accuracy. Can you please be more specific as what "that" is in your question.

[Edit] -  From this [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/57e35773f708f6d6129d643a7a237b2fbe0779eb/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L897) I gather that it should return the mean precision score for the test set only.

Comment: As you set RF to optimize for precision, then it should return its mean on [test set](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html?highlight=gridsearchcv#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV:~:text=Strategy%20to%20evaluate%20the%20performance%20of%20the%20cross%2Dvalidated%20model%20on%20the%20test%20set.), right?

Comment: I'm referring to the scoring parameter in the GridSearchCV. I have it set to precison to produce the best precison_score. The GridSearchCV reports that the best score (which should be precision?) is .9639. However, when I run the RF classifier using the best estimator from the GridSearchCV (which should produce the best score?) then the precision score is only .85.  See the classification report at end of code above. How do I get the .9639 precison with the RF classifier?

Comment: Yes, spot on. What I mean is: I am wondering if ` .9639` isn't the mean of both training and validation precision.

Comment: Could you please provide the line in your code where you calculate precision for the `rf_A.fit` objects?

Comment: I'm unsure. If I'm predicting on the test set should the score be closer to .9639?

Comment: prec = make_scorer(precision_score)
grid_rf = GridSearchCV(estimator = rf,   
   param_grid=params_rf, scoring=prec,  cv=10, n_jobs=-1, verbose=True)

Comment: Notice that ` return_train_score : bool, default=False
        If ``False``, the ``cv_results_`` attribute will not include training
        scores.` That surely means the attribute `best_score_` will not have the `train` data.